# Запуск приложения fast_api на хостинге от reg.ru

Tags: fastapi, hosting, uvicorn

Всем привет, я хочу запустить свое fast_api приложение (сам запуск происходит через uvicorn) на своем сайте reg.ru. Я делал все по [этому гайду](https://help.reg.ru/support/hosting/php-asp-net-i-skripty/kak-ustanovit-flask-na-hosting), единственное, что я поменял - вместо flask я использовал fast_api (ну и, конечно же, установил недостающие модули). Но в итоге код не работает (We're sorry, but something went wrong.). Можете подсказать, что именно я делаю не так?

[image: Ошибка]

`app.py`:

```py
import uvicorn
import fastapi

application = fastapi.FastAPI()
@application.get("/")
async def get():
    return fastapi.Response(content="Hello World", status_code=200, media_type='text/plain')

uvicorn.run(application, host='0.0.0.0', log_level='error')
```

`passenger_wsgi.py`:

```py
import sys

import os

INTERP = os.path.expanduser("/var/www/my_user/data/flaskenv/bin/python")
if sys.executable != INTERP:
   os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

from app import application
```

Comment: Во-первых, какая версия Python? Во-вторых, FastAPI не является WSGI-приложением, а значит для запуска придётся завернуть его в [обёртку-костыль](https://pypi.org/project/a2wsgi/), но это уже какой-то идиотизм

Comment: Версия ``Python 3.10.1``, а на счет костылей - какие тогда есть альтернативы?